# SQLALCHEMY: How to define a foreign key column that can reference multiple tables

Tags: database, sqlalchemy

Let's say I have 2 tables, student and teacher, each has id as primary key.

Then I have an activity table to record the activity a person does.

The activity table has id, activity_name, person_id, person_type columns

So person_id should reference either id in student or teacher table (based on person_type).

How to represent this in sqlalchemy?

Comment: Might be a good idea to mention which database you are using. I don't think many or any support a foreign key that references multiple tables like that.

Answer (score 0):

There’s not a direct way to do it. A foreign key is always between two specific tables only.

You’re dealing with a common pattern in databases: how to model subtypes / supertypes. Here you have teacher and student as subtypes of person.

You have three basic options.

(1) one table. You could have a Person table that contains all the attributes of both Teacher and Student, plus a type column. You would need logic at app or DB level to enforce which columns should be required, optional or forbidden by type. Here you could use a single foreign key from Activity to the Person table.

(2) N+1 tables. Have a Person table that has just attributes shared by all the subtypes; plus both a Teacher and a Student table with their unique attributes. Teacher and Student would be FK children of Person. You would need app or DB logic to ensure each a Person record was pointed to by one and only one Teacher or Student record. Here you could use a single foreign key from Activity to the Person table.

(3) N tables. Have separate Teacher and Student tables as you do now. Repeat attributes between them if necessary. Here you could create one foreign key from Activity to Teacher, and another from Activity to Student. You would need app or DB logic to ensure each Activity record points to either a Teacher record or a a student record, with the other being null.

Obvious trade offs to each approach.

See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance.html

Comment: I have thought about all these approaches. Is there a general guideline about when should I use which?

Comment: Not really. The choice probably boils down to which trade off is most acceptable to you, e.g. which of the app or DB logic scenarios would be easiest to implement, or has the lowest risk for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Usually for this problem people will use either:

1. [joined-table-inheritance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance.html#joined-table-inheritance): create a base person table with id and type, that student and teacher tables both share ids with, allowing activity table to just use persons(id) as its foreign key
2. [single-table-inheritance](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance): create one unified person table with all columns needed by teacher and student and include them based on a type, again activity just uses persons(id) as foreign key

I'm not sure of your exact requirements but another option might be to split person_id into employee_id and teacher_id and drop the type column in activity or leave it for your application to branch on using use to prevent NULL when the type is set using a unique constraint.  This might just further expand the problem if you do that in many more tables and might complicate queries.